# How to Append a element with a remove function with it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to append a list element with a remove function with it. I already created the remove function and I can appended the element but have no idea how to append the element with the remove function with it.

here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn1").click(function () {
            var listname = $('#listname').val();
            $(".container").append($('<ol>', {
                text: listname
            }));
        });


        $("#btn2").on('click', function () {
            var name = $('#name').val();
            $('ol').append($('<li>', {
                text: name
            }));
        });

        $('ol').on('click', '.btn3', function () {
            $(this).parent('li').remove();

        });

    });
</script>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <ol>
        <li>List item 1 <button class="btn3">remove</button></li>
        <li>List item 2 <button class="btn3">remove</button></li>
        <li>List item 3 <button class="btn3">remove</button></li>
    </ol>
    <form>
        <input id="name" type="text"> <button id="btn2">Append list items</button> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Tips, comments will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$("#btn2").on('click', function () {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    $('<li>', {
        text: name
    }).appendTo('ol').append($('<button />', {
        'class': 'btn3',
        text: 'Remove'
    }))
});
```

If the `ol` is added dynamically then

```
$(document).on('click', 'ol .btn3', function () {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KSzqM/)

Answer (score 0):

create `<li>` append `<button>` to it.. and then append it to the `<ol>`

try this

```
 $("#btn2").on('click',function(){
 var name = $('#name').val();
 var $li=$('<li>', { text: name}); //creating li element.
   $li.append($('<button />',{text:"remove","class":"btn3"}).appendTo('ol');
   //--^^^^^^^^^---- append created button to lu            ---append  li to ol
});
```